# CodeIgniter get multiple items in config file

Tags: codeigniter

I would like to get multiple items in config file in CodeIgniter.

I want to loop this array then echo it . how to do that ?

Config file:

```
$config['test']=array('AAA','BBB');
```

How can i echo those two items in controller ?

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

try doing like this :

```
$this->load->config('your_config_file_name');
$test_arr = $this->config->item('test');
foreach($test_arr as $t){
echo $t;
}
```

OR

```
print_r($test_arr);
```

Comment: I want to display 'AAA','BBB'. how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

supposed you have loaded config file already

```
$item_arr = array();
$items = $this->config->config['test'];   // get the array items from config
foreach($items AS $item){
    $item_arr[] = "'".$item."'";
}
$all_items = implode(',',$item_arr);
echo $all_items;
```

Comment: I want to display 'AAA','BBB'. how to do that ?